# Simplifying $\int f(t) \delta(\mathbf x - t\mathbf x_0) dt$

Tags: dirac-delta

Consider two n-dimensional vectors $\mathbf{x, x_0}$ and the expression
$$
\int_0^\infty f(t) \delta(\mathbf x - t\mathbf x_0) dt
$$
where $\delta$ is the n-dimensional Dirac delta function. Intuitively this means that $\mathbf x$ is collinear with $\mathbf x_0$ and that there is a weight $f(t)$ where $t$ is the "slope".

Now $\mathbf x = t \mathbf x_0, t > 0$ iff $\mathbf{x\cdot x_0} = \mathbf{|x||x_0|}$ with $t = \frac{\mathbf{x\cdot x_0}}{|\mathbf x_0|^2}$

So I am naively wondering if I may write
$$
\int_0^\infty f(t) \delta(\mathbf x - t\mathbf x_0) dt
= f\left( \frac{\mathbf{x\cdot x_0}}{|\mathbf x_0|^2} \right) \delta(\mathbf{x\cdot x_0 - |x||x_0|})
= f\left( \frac{|\mathbf x|}{|\mathbf x_0|} \right) \delta(\mathbf{x\cdot x_0 - |x||x_0|})
$$
and also whether there might even be a simpler expression?

Many thanks in advance!
p

Comment: You can drop the delta function since
$$
\int_0^\infty f(t)\delta(g(x,t))dt = f(t_0)
$$
where $t_0$ is obtained from finding
$$
g(x,t_0) = 0
$$
which you have found. The other condition is that 
$$
t_0 \in (0, \infty)
$$

Comment: except that the LHS depends on x whereas your RHS doesn't...  ultimately the result "..." will be inserted in an expression that depends on x: $\int_{\mathbb R^n} g(\mathbf x) \cdots d\mathbf x$

Comment: The RHS does depend on $x$ implicitly via the zeros of $g(x,t)$. If there are many zeros then you will have a sum on the RHS. This is a property of Dirac delta functions.

Comment: OK but I think your line of reasoning only works for 1-dimensional Dirac delta.  As a counter-example take f(t) = 1, n =2, X = (x,y), X0 = (a,b), then $$\int \delta(x - at)\delta(y - bt)dt = a^{-1} \int \delta(x/a - t)\delta(y - bt)dt = a^{-1}\delta(y - b/a x) = \delta(ay - bx) $$